# Suggested tags - both sql-server and mysql are suggested by the system

Tags: feature-request, tags, suggested-tags

I noticed that there's quite a lot of questions asked especially by new users that have both tags [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server) and [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql). That makes sense in some cases (e.g. linking between those RDBMS's) but the vast majority of those questions are actually about only one of them.

This makes it hard to answer some of those questions if the specific RDBMS is not mentioned in the text of the question or the title.

It turns out that both tags are suggested for those kind of questions. I copied the text of one of those questions to a new question and yes, both tags are there (see the screenshot). If people asking such questions don't pay attention, we end up having to always ask the same question: "Which RDBMS is that?"

This is quite annoying and time consuming to sort out the tags as you can't always guess RDBMS (and you shouldn't be guessing anyway). Can that be fixed?

[image]

Comment: I suspect it's because it's obvious it's SQL and these are the two most common tags to go with it (let's be honest it's not Oracle or PostgreSQL). What's the way out? Tag hierarchies?

Comment: How should it be fixed? Clarifying my question - do you mean that neither or a particular one should be suggested or some other solution?

Comment: I'm not completely sure but maybe it could leave just [tag:sql] which is also suggested.

Comment: I disagree with your suggested fix, because there are already more than enough SQL questions that don't indicate which RDBMS they're using, but asking questions where that information is really needed to post a specific answer. (Not downvoting your post; just referencing your commented suggestion.)

Comment: @KenWhite I agree, it's not the best solution. Better solution would be maybe: if it tries to suggest tag [tag:sql], it should ask for one of the RDBMS specific tags.

Comment: +1 because I probably re-tag about 10 of these questions a day. Most beginners don't realize that sql-server and mysql are actually different things (either the product could just as easily be called MySQL Server, or they think they're talking about their own sql ("mysql")). However, while I agree this is a pervasive issue, I don't know that there is a fix that is both effective and straightforward to implement. Maybe like the "are you sure you meant to post a second answer?" there could be a question like "are you sure you meant to tag with two different RDBMS platforms?"

Comment: That would be an ideal thing, because it doesn't force anything and it doesn't prevent the occasional question which really is relevant to two platforms. I just don't know how feasible it would be to have this very specialized behavior for a handful of tags, when a probably significant number of people will just dismiss the prompt anyway...

Comment: @AaronBertrand I like your solution but as you said it may not be easy to implement...

Comment: looks more like a [meta-tag:feature-request]

Comment: well, it's certainly not a [meta-tag:bug]

Comment: Ok, made it a feature request, I guess you're right.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, this is a prevalent problem.

I often have to get confirmation from users who tag questions with both [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) and [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server). Usually the question doesn't have to do with both platforms; the OP just either thinks that MySQL is a "sql server" or that their SQL Server problem is, to them, "my sql problem." It can be tedious to get this information, and in a lot of cases either the question can't be answered until the OP responds, or the question quickly gets littered with answers that guess which platform the OP meant (sometimes it is obvious from other aspects of the question, sometimes not so much).

Here are just a couple of examples from the last week, and these are only ones where I've bothered to comment (I've seen many others that may have been corrected by now).

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21591761/synchronize-between-two-database-tables
- [Creating a foreign key in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21536164/mysql-server-creating-foreign-key)
- [Connect to MySql using IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21504818/connect-to-mysql-using-ip-address)
- [Can I do a not in except for in my SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21461880/can-i-do-a-not-in-except-for-in-my-sql-query)

While there is an occasional need for both tags (e.g. migrating data or syntax between platforms), this is pretty rare.

I think this is a problem highly prevalent among new users, and I'm sure it's due to the tag suggestions low-rep users get when they include things like "SQL" in the title of their question. And I think they just blindly click all of the suggestions because that's what they think the system wants them to do.

When someone chooses both tags, I'd love for there to be some kind of hint or warning that tells them it is uncommon to need to tag with both. They can dismiss it, so maybe it can just be a JavaScript:alert, but I'm thinking something like this:

> [image]