# Should there be a way to restrict common incorrect tag-combos (like Java and JavaScript)?

Tags: discussion, tags

Sometimes confused newbies post Java questions and tag it with both Java and JavaScript.

Should the system perhaps block strange tag-combos that make no sense?

Edit: So it turns out that sometimes you do mix Java and JavaScript ;-)  thanks -Doorknob

Comment: I get the feeling that if the OP is able to confuse such tags, the question probably isn't going to be a good question anyway...

Comment: @Mysticial - Ah, fair point. That's certainly true

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207274/suggested-tags-both-sql-server-and-mysql-are-suggested-by-the-system

Comment: That's what we have tag synonyms for. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Java and JavaScript could make sense together; for example, interacting with a Java applet with JavaScript, or JSP.

The false positives would not be worth the slight benefit that would be gained by this feature. This is what editing is for, and such incorrect tags are already quickly edited out anyway.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't kno that. Cool, thanks!!

Comment: Adding to that; Java has a [built in scripting engine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/) and one of the supported scripts is, you guessed it, javascript